# Stop Script From Duplicating Events

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I have a script I'm using to add events from sheets to a public google calendar. The intent of the calendar is to show all approved travel to a particular site. Despite an error I get ("Cannot find method createEvent(string,string,string,object). (line 26, file "CalendarEvent") the script does seem to work (I can at least see the events on the calendar). One issue I'm having is it's creating duplicate events. I saw a similar question that addressed this duplication issue, however, the answer didn't seem to fix my issue. Here's my script so far:

```
function CreateBPEvent() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange('AB1').getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("###");
  var lr = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
  Logger.log(lr);
  var count = spreadsheet.getRange("Z3:AC"+lr+"").getValues(); 
  for (x=0; x<count.length; x++) {
    var shift = count[x];
    var title = shift[0];
    var startTime = shift[1];
    var endTime = shift[2];
    var description = shift[3];   
    var options = {
      'description': description,
    }
    eventCal.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, options);
  }
}
```

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

- You don't want to create the duplicated events in the calendar.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, when `startTime` and `endTime` are the same, the duplicated event is not created.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
eventCal.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, options);
```

To:

```
var events = eventCal.getEvents(startTime, endTime);
if (events.length == 0) {
  eventCal.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, options);
}
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, when `startTime`, `endTime` and `title` are the same, the duplicated event is not created.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
eventCal.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, options);
```

To:

```
var events = eventCal.getEvents(startTime, endTime, {search: title});
if (events.length == 0) {
  eventCal.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, options);
}
```

or

```
var events = eventCal.getEvents(startTime, endTime);
if (events.length == 0 || events.filter(function(e) {return e.getTitle() == title}).length == 0) {
  eventCal.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, options);
}
```

### Note:

- About the error message of `"Cannot find method createEvent(string,string,string,object). (line 26, file "CalendarEvent"`, the arguments of `createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, options)` are string, date object, date object and object, respectively. So please be careful this.

### References:

- [getEvents(startTime, endTime)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#geteventsstarttime,-endtime)
- [getEvents(startTime, endTime, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#geteventsstarttime,-endtime,-options)
- [createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createeventtitle,-starttime,-endtime,-options)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried both options (I prefer the method with unique starttime, endtime & title), however, I'm still getting the same error message and it's still duplicating the previously entered events.

Comment: @Jamie Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About the error message of `Cannot find method createEvent(string,string,string,object)`, in order to replicate the issue, it is required to confirm the Spreadsheet. So can you provide a sample Spreadsheet? Of course, please remove your personal information. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, here's a copy of the data (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BqaIYrGlCcaidRcHSin0TJicc8EcFjDYD1xO8BzrWnM/edit?usp=sharing) Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Jamie Thank you for providing the sample Spreadsheet. I tested the script using your provided Spreadsheet. But unfortunately, I cannot replicate your issue of `Cannot find method createEvent(string,string,string,object)`. Can I ask you about the flow of the error? This is due to my poor skill. I apologize for this.